# Sqlite command to retrieve multiple message with single number

Tags: android, mysql, sql

I have created a table with 2 columns, say col1 & col2...
In col1 I have inserted contact numbers and in col2 I have inserted contact messages

The problem is --- how can I retrieve  distinct  shows distinct number with only single message , I want all the messages of that number...

I need output in the following format...

Fetch the number and all messages corresponding to that number

This is my database columns .

Col1(number) Col2(message) 
79802828.      A
 79802828 .    B
 12345.            C
 12345.            D
 7890.              E

I want the output as

Col1(number)         Col2(message)

79802828. ---------------- A 
                                            B
79802829. ---------------------- C
                                            D
79802830. ------------------------ E

2.the number should be unique with all messages

3.After retrieved this I want to pass unique number and latest (if the number contains more then one message I want to show latest one)message to my main listview as

NUMBER MESAAGE

4.when I click on the listview item it should show all message(latest and old) in that listview

Comment: instead of "group by" use "where col1 = xyz"

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat() to get all messages with a separator (, by default  but you can specify the separator)

```
select col1, group_concat(col2) from table_name group by col1;
```

You can specify the separator as:

```
group_concat(col2 SEPARATOR '; ')
```

Comment: Yes,but when I use group_concat it shows the messages in a row with comma separator how can I pass that to a list view as one by one item

Comment: You can use java split method (using the separator) to convert the string into list of messages.

Comment: @user8515823 Can you specify the exact output format that you want to achieve?

Comment: @user8515823 Retrive data using the above query and store the data as a java Map (number, message_list). Use java split on the second column to obtain the list of messages.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fetch the number and all messages corresponding to that number

This is my database columns .

Col1(number)               Col2(message)
         -------                               ----------
79802828.                                   A
79802828.                                   B
12345.                                         C
12345.                                         D
7890.                                           E

I want the output as

Col1(number)               Col2(message)
         -------                               ----------
79802828.   ---------------------- A
                                               B
12345.         ----------------------  C
                                               D
7890.          ----------------------    E

2.the number should be unique with all messages

3.After retrieved this I want to pass unique number and latest (if the number contains more then one message I want to show latest one)message to my main listview as

NUMBER 
MESAAGE

4.when I click on the listview item it should show all  message(latest and old) in that listview